# how to handle bad pointers

Tags: c++, html, visual-c++, mshtml

all, as the title asked how to handle bad pointers. I am using MSHTML::IHTMLStyle to handle style features that when I read in a snippet of html code, I collect some specific style features among all the html elements within the code.

```
hash_map<wstring, wstring> CMyAppDlg::GetNodeStyles(VARIANT varSrc)
{
    long lLength = 0;
    MSHTML::IHTMLDocument2Ptr htmDoc = NULL;
    MSHTML::IHTMLElementCollectionPtr pElemColl = NULL;
    MSHTML::IHTMLElementPtr pChElem = NULL;
    MSHTML::IHTMLStylePtr pStyle = NULL;
    _bstr_t bstrtTagName;
    hash_map<wstring, wstring> hmStyles;
    SAFEARRAY *psaStrings = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_VARIANT, 0, 1);
    CoCreateInstance(CLSID_HTMLDocument, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IHTMLDocument2, (void**) &htmDoc);

    VARIANT *param;
    HRESULT hr = SafeArrayAccessData(psaStrings, (LPVOID*)&param);
    param->vt = VT_BSTR;
    param->bstrVal = varSrc.bstrVal;

    hr = SafeArrayUnaccessData(psaStrings);
  hr = htmDoc->write(psaStrings);

    pElemColl = htmDoc->all;
    lLength = pElemColl->length;
    for(long i = 0; i < lLength; i++)
    {
        pChElem = pElemColl->item(_variant_t(i), _variant_t());

        MessageBox(pChElem->tagName, _T("The tag name of this html element is"), MB_OK);
        pStyle = pChElem->style;

        pStyle->fontStyle;

        hmStyles[wstring(pStyle->fontStyle)] = L"FontStyle";

        hmStyles[wstring(pStyle->fontFamily)] = L"FontFamily";

        hmStyles[wstring(pStyle->textDecoration)] = L"TextDecoration";
    }

    return hmStyles;
}
```

the problem is when read in an arbitrary html code like:

```
<A href='/servlet/BookDetailsPL?bi=1257056972&amp;tab=1&amp;searchurl=bt.x%3D44%26bt.y%3D10%26sts%3Dt%26tn%3Dharry%2Bpotter' cmImpressionSent='1'>The Orchard Bookshop.</A> <SPAN class=scndInfo>(Hayes., UK, United Kingdom)</SPAN>
```

IHTMLDocument write() will automatically adds plain "HTML", "TITLE", "HEAD", "BODY", etc, to the code, that they dont contain any styles; so

pStyle->fontStyle;
pStyle->fontFamily and
pStyle->textDecoration
will return bad pointers of _bstr_t type, that these bad pointers lead my program crashed. My question is how to avoid these bad pointers, like setting an condition to by-pass them.

```
MSHTML::IHTMLStyle::GetfontStyle returned   {<Bad Ptr> (1)} _bstr_t
MSHTML::IHTMLStyle::GetfontFamily returned  {<Bad Ptr> (1)} _bstr_t
MSHTML::IHTMLStyle::GettextDecoration returned  {<Bad Ptr> (1)} _bstr_t
```

here is the doc on IHTMLElement style property:

HRESULT IHTMLElement::get_style(IHTMLStyle **p);

p is the address of a pointer to the IHTMLStyle interface for the style sheet.

Comment: Are they "bad" pointers, or "null" pointers? A bad pointer implies it points to invalid memory, a null pointer implies `(ptr == 0)` is true, and hence is testable.

Comment: the debugger said they are bad ptr, and pStyle is not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is caused by using smart pointers on `IHTMLDocument2`, `IHTMLElement` and `IHTMLElementCollection`, and `IHTMLStyle`. I solved the bad pointers problem by declaring normal pointers on them, and dont know why smart pointers failed me this time, and seems to be failed in some other places too.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what this MSHTML stuff is but I'm guessing `pChElem->style` is not a pointer.

In which case you are assigning a style *value* to a style *pointer* which would certainly be a bad pointer. I'd recommend dereferencing first except that you aren't allocating any of these pointers so if you don't want to just use the element's style perhaps something like this is what you're looking for:

```
pStyle = &pChElem->style;
```

**Edit:** Also did a little research out of my own curiosity about these interfaces and I believe `item` returns an `HRESULT` not an element from what I see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa703930(v=vs.85).aspx unless you wrapped it or I'm missing something at first blush.

Comment: since i am using smart pointer on IHTMLStyle, pStyle is declared as IHTMLStylePtr, and pChElem is also a smart pointer on IHTMLElementPtr that PChElem->style returns IHTMLStylePtr. and when i debugged the code, pStyle is not null or a bad pointer.

Comment: Ah ok then in that case what do you get if you do `MessageBox(L"FontStyle", std::wstring(pStyle->fontStyle).c_str(), MB_OK);`

Comment: pElemColl->item(_variant_t(i), _variant_t()) returns an IHTMLElementPtr at index _variant_t(i); and MessageBox(pChElem->tagName, _T("The tag name of this html element is") is a test and does show the HTML element name at that index.

Comment: when i tried MessageBox(L"FontStyle", std::wstring(pStyle->fontStyle).c_str(), MB_OK); the program crashed, with an error msg: "invalid null pointer"

Comment: I'm still thinking that `pStyle = pChElem->style;` is your problem because that is the point right before things stop working as expected.

Comment: i also tried pStyle = &pChElem->style; but the program wont compiled

Comment: Ok, that just means it is returning pointer so you had it right. I'm unfamiliar with these COM interfaces so it just looked odd to me. If you set a break point can you add `pStyle` and `pChElem->style` to the watch and see what `fontStyle` is? Should be _normal_, _italic_ or _oblique_

Comment: i think the point is when i read in a VARIANT html source string, the IHTMLDocument write() automatically added "HTML", "TITLE", "HEAD", "BODY", etc, to the string, if the string is some kinda random and adding those elements will make it a real html doc. Now, when i walked through all the html elements in the html doc, the first element is "HTML", and it doesnt include any inline styles, so i think it's no surprised that fontStyle alone with other styles are bad pointers, but i dont understand why pChElem->style can still returned something; and I simply want to avoid those bad ptrs.

Comment: the following is what pChElem->style returned:  MSHTML::IHTMLElement::Getstyle returned {0x023ff400} _com_ptr_t<_com_IIID<MSHTML::IHTMLStyle,&_GUID_3050f25e_98b5_11cf_bb82_00aa00bdce0b> >

Comment: but fontStyle is a bad ptr, as i have edited and listed the debugged info in the original post.

Comment: bummer, well I'm not sure what's going wrong. This is why I don't use COM, debugging is such a pain.